# Problem involving a probability distribution and random variables

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable

A speculator invests in the currency markets. Let $X_n$ denote the amount of money in her account at the end of day $n$. Her daily gains, $J_n = X_n - X_{n-1}$, are independent random variables, each having distribution as shown below:

$$ P(J_n = j) = 0.18, \; \; if \; \; j = - £200.$$
$$ P(J_n = j) = 0.30, \; \; if \; \; j = - £100.$$
$$ P(J_n = j) = 0.12, \; \; if \; \; j = £0.$$
$$ P(J_n = j) = 0.40, \; \; if \; \; j = + £100.$$

The speculator's aim is to increase her capital to £4000, when she will stop trading. She will also stop if the account falls to zero.

Let $h_k$ denote the probability that the speculator's capital ultimately reaches £4000, given that her account currently holds $k \times £100$.

Now, how do I calculate the values of $h_0$, $h_{-1}$ and $h_{40}$ ?

Comment: you wrote $k×£100$ then $h_0=0×£100=0$. Do you pointed all task condition?

Comment: is it a self-study question?

Comment: Looks like a self study question, so I would write a helpful comment: Lets name the four cases as $Case A: j = -200, P(J_n=j) = 0.18 , \\Case B: j = -100, P(J_n=j) = 0.30 , \\ Case C: j = 0, P(J_n=j) = 0.12 , \\ Case D: j = +100, P(J_n=j) = 0.40$. Then for $h_0$, speculator start from 0, and reaches to 4000. Which means if there are $n_1$ case A, $n_2$ case B, $k$ case C then there will be $40 + 2n_1 + n_2$ case D. Then you have to find probability of all these events happening together

Comment: @DwaipayanGupta, i think $X_0$ should be greater than 0 because a speculator should have money to buy/sell a currency. What is meant $h_{-1}$? A speculator can reach not only to £4000 but above £4000, e.g., $19 \times 200 + 1 \times (-100)+2 \times 200 = 4100$.

Comment: **Aren't these questions trivial?**  As you have defined them, $h_0$ is the chance of reaching 4000 starting with 0, but the rules say the trader immediately stops.  Similarly, $h_{40}$ means the trader already has 4000 and therefore stops.  $h_{-1}$ means she has negative capital and cannot trade at all.

Answer (score 1):

Since the expected return is -26 per round, it is hard to imagine that there is much hope to turn 100 into 4000, but it is, of course possible.

One way to approach this is to use a Markov chain.  If the states are 0, 100, 200, ... 4,000, with 0 and 4000 being absorptive, then the transition matrix looks something like:

\begin{bmatrix}
\space\space\space 1 \space\space\space\space  0 \space\space\space\space  0 \space\space\space 0 \space\space\space 0 \space\space\space 0 \space\space\space 0 \space...\space 0 \\
 .48 \space\space .12 \space\space.4 \space\space\space 0 \space\space\space 0 \space\space\space 0 \space\space\space 0 \space... 0 \\
  .18 \space\space .3 \space\space .12 \space\space .4 \space\space\space 0 \space\space\space 0 \space\space\space 0 \space... 0 \\
  0  \space\space .18 \space\space .3 \space\space .12 \space\space .4 \space\space\space 0\space\space\space 0 \space... 0 \\
...\\
  0  \space\space\space 0  \space\space\space ... \space\space 0  \space\space\space .18 \space\space .3 \space\space .12 \space\space .4  \\
  0  \space\space\space 0  \space\space\space ... \space\space\space 0 \space\space\space 0  \space\space\space 0 \space\space\space 0 \space\space\space 0 \space\space 1  \\
\end{bmatrix}

Of course I'm assuming that losing 200, when you only have 100 is the same as losing 100 (you end up with nothing and no chance for recovery).

If you multiply your starting state [ 0 1 0 0 0 0  .... 0] (state holding 100) by the above transition matrix raised to a fairly high power, you get a vector with the probabilities of each state being final.  States 2 to 40 slowly go away, and the 41st element goes to about $5.2 \cdot 10^{-8}$ and the 1st is 1 minus that.

For higher starting amounts just adjust the row vector above [ 0 0 1 0 ... 0 ] for starting with 200, etc.

Comment: What you have written obviously is not a transition matrix: its rows do not sum to unity.

Comment: I think each row sums to unity - I checked with my 41x41 when I gen'd it in matlab.  Did you miss the decimal points?

Comment: You're right: I did overlook one. (+1)